# how to Volume of Tetrahedron each face offset

Tags: python, sympy

How to Volume of Tetrahedron plane offset?

Calculate the parallel faces of each face of the triangular pyramid, and calculate the intersection points of each face at four points. The volume is calculated from the coordinates of the intersection calculation.

①What should I do?

```
from sympy import *
def myIntersection_of_3_planes(a,b,c):
    ab = a.intersection(b)
    abc = ab[0].intersection(c)
    return abc[0]

def myUnitVector(C):
    D=Matrix([[0], [0], [0]])
    myL=sqrt(C[0]**2+C[1]**2+C[2]**2)
    D[0]=C[0]/myL
    D[1]=C[1]/myL
    D[2]=C[2]/myL
    return D

def my3Point_Offset(myT0,myT1,myT2,my03):
    mmy03=myCrossProduct(Matrix(myT1)-Matrix(myT0),Matrix(myT2)-Matrix(myT0))
    mmy03=myUnitVector(mmy03)
    mmy03[0]=float(mmy03[0])*my03
    mmy03[1]=float(mmy03[1])*my03
    mmy03[2]=float(mmy03[2])*my03
    myT0S=Matrix([[0], [0], [0]])
    myT1S=Matrix([[0], [0], [0]])
    myT2S=Matrix([[0], [0], [0]])
    myT0S[0]=myT0[0]-mmy03[0]
    myT0S[1]=myT0[1]-mmy03[1]
    myT0S[2]=myT0[2]-mmy03[2]
    myT1S[0]=myT1[0]-mmy03[0]
    myT1S[1]=myT1[1]-mmy03[1]
    myT1S[2]=myT1[2]-mmy03[2]
    myT2S[0]=myT2[0]-mmy03[0]
    myT2S[1]=myT2[1]-mmy03[1]
    myT2S[2]=myT2[2]-mmy03[2]
    return myT0S,myT1S,myT2S

def my4Point_Intersection(myT0,myT1,myT2,myT3,my01,my02,my03):
        aa=my3Point_Offset(myT0, myT1, myT2, my03[0])
        bb=my3Point_Offset(myT0, myT2, myT3, my01[0])
        cc=my3Point_Offset(myT0, myT3, myT1, my02[0])
        p11, p12, p13 = map(Point3D, [aa[0],aa[1],aa[2]])
        p21, p22, p23 = map(Point3D, [bb[0],bb[1],bb[2]])
        p31, p32, p33 = map(Point3D, [cc[0],cc[1],cc[2]])
        a = Plane(p11, p12, p13)
        b = Plane(p21, p22, p23)
        c = Plane(p31, p32, p33)
        ans=myIntersection_of_3_planes(a, b, c)
        return ans

def myCrossProduct(A, B):
    return expand(Matrix([
            [A[1,0]*B[2,0]-A[2,0]*B[1,0]],
            [A[2,0]*B[0,0]-A[0,0]*B[2,0]],
            [A[0,0]*B[1,0]-A[1,0]*B[0,0]]
                                ]))

def myIntersection_of_3_planes(a,b,c):
    ab = a.intersection(b)
    abc = ab[0].intersection(c)
    return abc[0]

def myVolumeTetrahedron(myTetrahedron):
    my_PQRS=Matrix(myTetrahedron)
    my_S   =Matrix([myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[3]])
    return float(det(my_PQRS[:3, :3].T - my_S.T)/6)

myTetrahedron=[[0,0,0],[10,0,0],[0,10,0],[0,0,10]]
myOffset     =[[0]    ,[0]     ,[0]     ,[0]     ]
myT0=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3], myOffset[1],myOffset[2],myOffset[3])
myT1=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0], myOffset[2],myOffset[3],myOffset[0])
myT2=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1], myOffset[3],myOffset[0],myOffset[1])
myT3=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2], myOffset[0],myOffset[1],myOffset[2])
myTetrahedron=[myT0,myT1,myT2,myT3]
print("#",'{:.3f}'.format(myVolumeTetrahedron(myTetrahedron)))
#
myTetrahedron=[[0,0,0],[10,0,0],[0,10,0],[0,0,10]]
myOffset     =[[1]    ,[1]     ,[1]    ,[1]      ]
myT0=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3], myOffset[1],myOffset[2],myOffset[3])
myT1=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0], myOffset[2],myOffset[3],myOffset[0])
myT2=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1], myOffset[3],myOffset[0],myOffset[1])
myT3=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2], myOffset[0],myOffset[1],myOffset[2])
myTetrahedron=[myT0,myT1,myT2,myT3]
print("#",'{:.3f}'.format(myVolumeTetrahedron(myTetrahedron)))
# (10*10)/2*10/3=166.667
# -166.667
# -119.877
```

②I'm looking for a web page with an official formula

bellow

I try with numpy.

```
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
def myIntersection_of_3_planes(a,b,c):
    ab = a.intersection(b)
    abc = ab[0].intersection(c)
    return abc[0]

def myUnitVector(C):
    return np.array(C)/sqrt(C[0]**2+C[1]**2+C[2]**2)

def my3Point_Offset(myT0,myT1,myT2,my03):
    mmy03=my03*np.array(myUnitVector(myCrossProduct(Matrix(myT1)-Matrix(myT0),Matrix(myT2)-Matrix(myT0))))
    return Matrix((np.array(myT0) - np.array(mmy03))[0]), \
           Matrix((np.array(myT1) - np.array(mmy03))[0]), \
           Matrix((np.array(myT2) - np.array(mmy03))[0])

def my4Point_Intersection(myT0,myT1,myT2,myT3,my01,my02,my03):
        aa=my3Point_Offset(myT0, myT1, myT2, my03[0])
        bb=my3Point_Offset(myT0, myT2, myT3, my01[0])
        cc=my3Point_Offset(myT0, myT3, myT1, my02[0])
        p11, p12, p13 = map(Point3D, [aa[0],aa[1],aa[2]])
        p21, p22, p23 = map(Point3D, [bb[0],bb[1],bb[2]])
        p31, p32, p33 = map(Point3D, [cc[0],cc[1],cc[2]])
        a = Plane(p11, p12, p13)
        b = Plane(p21, p22, p23)
        c = Plane(p31, p32, p33)
        ans=myIntersection_of_3_planes(a, b, c)
        return ans

def myCrossProduct(A, B):
    return expand(Matrix([
            [A[1,0]*B[2,0]-A[2,0]*B[1,0]],
            [A[2,0]*B[0,0]-A[0,0]*B[2,0]],
            [A[0,0]*B[1,0]-A[1,0]*B[0,0]]
                                ]))

def myIntersection_of_3_planes(a,b,c):
    ab = a.intersection(b)
    abc = ab[0].intersection(c)
    return abc[0]

def myVolumeTetrahedron(myTetrahedron):
    my_PQRS=Matrix(myTetrahedron)
    my_S   =Matrix([myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[3]])
    return float(det(my_PQRS[:3, :3].T - my_S.T)/6)

myTetrahedron=[[0,0,0],[10,0,0],[0,10,0],[0,0,10]]
myOffset     =[[0]    ,[0]     ,[0]     ,[0]     ]
myT0=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3], myOffset[1],myOffset[2],myOffset[3])
myT1=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0], myOffset[2],myOffset[3],myOffset[0])
myT2=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1], myOffset[3],myOffset[0],myOffset[1])
myT3=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2], myOffset[0],myOffset[1],myOffset[2])
myTetrahedron=[myT0,myT1,myT2,myT3]
print("#",'{:.3f}'.format(myVolumeTetrahedron(myTetrahedron)))
#
myTetrahedron=[[0,0,0],[10,0,0],[0,10,0],[0,0,10]]
myOffset     =[[1]    ,[1]     ,[1]     ,[1]     ]
myT0=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3], myOffset[1],myOffset[2],myOffset[3])
myT1=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0], myOffset[2],myOffset[3],myOffset[0])
myT2=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[2],myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1], myOffset[3],myOffset[0],myOffset[1])
myT3=my4Point_Intersection(myTetrahedron[3],myTetrahedron[0],myTetrahedron[1],myTetrahedron[2], myOffset[0],myOffset[1],myOffset[2])
myTetrahedron=[myT0,myT1,myT2,myT3]
print("#",'{:.3f}'.format(myVolumeTetrahedron(myTetrahedron)))
# (10*10)/2*10/3=166.667
# -166.667
# -165.517
```

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly? You are drawing a tetrahedron in 3D space, then slicing it with a plane. Finally, you want to find the area on one side of the plane?

Comment: CrossProduct。offset plus or minus。How should I distinguish between right-handed and left-handed?

Answer (score 0):

How would you do something like this with calculus? Before thinking about the 3 dimensional space, consider the 2d: Area under a parabola sliced by a line.

```
y1=(x-1)^2
y2=x
```

You can easily visualize that the area is the difference between the integral of line and the integral of the parabola.

```
integral(y1) = 1/3(x-1)^3
integral(y2) = 1/2(x^2) ...

integral(y1)|(bounds) – integral(y2)|(bounds) = 1/3(x-1)^3 |(bounds) – 1/2(x^2) |(bounds)
```

However, we'll notice that this example includes negative areas below the x-axis. This is curable with absolute values.

The same principles apply in n-dimensional space. In your situation, your tetrahedron is a 3d shape being sliced by a 2d shape. Using absolute values will keep your shape above the x-axis (thus positive).